# Register Startup Script in MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I realise this has been asked quite a few times for different languages / versions of .NET and MVC.

With MVC4, what is currently the accepted way to register a Javascript Startup Script? I want to fire a script off after the page has finished loading, is there a built in method or should I just be using jQuery to do it?

Comment: If this has been asked for previous versions of MVC, did you have any trouble with using those answers?

Comment: In case with the latest edition the accepted way has changed :) Technology doesn't stand still

Comment: Use JQuery to fire a script on document.ready it will be the easiest way

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399592/cassette-bundles-vs-mvc4-bundles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Registering Startup Scripts" is a concept derived from ASP.Net WebForms, MVC has no such concept. To reference a "global" script file to be used on multiple pages add the script reference (`<script></script>`) to a *Master View*. To reference a script that is used on a single page/view reference it in the view itself.

MVC promotes *Separation of Concerns* enabling you to *separate* your view logic (scripts) from your domain/routing logic. Thus, mixing JavaScript, which is a client-side technology, with server-side code is mitigated if not eliminated.

---

ASP.Net 4 does come with *[Script Bundling & Minification](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389545/ASP-NET-MVC4-Bundling-and-Minification)* abilities which would enable the bundling & minification of script references to better manage scenarios where an application has numerous script files.

http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-bundling-and.html

Comment: And we're all better for it, too.